# no method on use_ssl = true

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to send post request using rails controller, however i faced issue, when i cant make controller accept use_ssl = true.
Here is my code

```
require "net/http"
require "uri"

params = {'requestId' => '1', 
  'merchantId' => 'merchantid'
  'version' => '1.0.6', 
  'locale' => 'en_US', 
  'externalUserId' => '1234', 
  'partnerId' => 'partnerid', 
  'emailAddress' => 'test@email.com', 
  'deviceDTO' => "{'id' => '123123213', 'deviceType' => 'samsung'}",
  'timestamp' => Time.now.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%L%z')
}

url = URI.parse('https://example.com')
http = Net::HTTP::Post.new(url.host)
http.set_form_data(params)
#http.use_ssl = true
#http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER


res = Net::HTTP.start(url.hostname, url.port) do |h|
  h.request(http)
  h.use_ssl = true
  h.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
end
```

errors are :

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `use_ssl=' for #<Net::HTTP::Post POST>
NoMethodError: undefined method `verify_mode=' for #<Net::HTTP::Post POST>
```

UPD
error now

```
Errno::ECONNRESET: Connection reset by peer
```

Comment: Is you rails app setup to run in ssl mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`use_ssl` is a method in `Net::HTTP`, you are creating a `Net::HTTP::Post` object.

You might want to do

```
url = URI.parse('https://example.com/')
http = Net::HTTP.new(url.host, url.port)
if url.scheme == 'https'
  http.use_ssl = true
  http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER
end
http.post(url.path, params)
```

Comment: how do i do Post request with use_ssl without Post object?
error now `Errno::ECONNRESET: Connection reset by peer`